# Thermoelectric diffusion equation

Tags: thermodynamics, electrostatics, thermoelectricity

The speed of diffusion of uncharged point-like particles from one volume with concentration $n_1$ to another with concentration $n_2$ after removing the wall between them depends on $n_1 - n_2$ by $\dot{n} = (n_1-n_2)/\tau_0$ with some time constant $\tau_0$.

But what happens when the particles carry a charge $q$: they will diffuse away from each other with higher speed, but will also be repelled by the ions in the other volume. How does the "thermoelectric" diffusion equation look like? Is it like $\dot{n} = (n_1-n_2)^{\alpha_1(q)}/\tau_1(q)$ with $\alpha_1(0) = 1, \tau_1(0) = \tau_0$?

If so: How do $\alpha_1, \tau_1$ depend on $q$?

(Is "thermoelectric diffusion" the correct name for this problem? Or better "electrothermal"? I have even read "electrotonic".)

Comment: The will be no such quantities like concentrations $n_1$ and $n_2$ after removing the wall. The will be spatially and time-dependent concentration n(x,t), which is the solution of the Fokker-Planck equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of situation frequently comes up in semiconductor device physics and electrochemistry (which conceptually overlap although they tend to use [annoyingly inconsistent terminology](http://sjbyrnes.com/fermiterminology.html)). I think this is most often called the drift-diffusion-poisson equation.

In a semiconductor example, the inputs in your analysis are: An initial electron (and/or hole) distribution in space, a density-of-states distribution in space, and a background charge distribution in space.

Then at each timestep, the concentration profile n(x,t) gives rise to an electric (galvani) potential profile V(x,t) by the poisson equation, which in turn determines an electrochemical potential profile, which in turn determines the flow of electrons.

It's hard to say anything generic about the solution to this problem, within the space of a stackexchange answer. The phenomenology of this equation is essentially the entire fields of semiconductor device physics and electrochemistry.

In the particular example you have in mind, I think your analysis is going awry even before the wall between the chambers is removed. If the starting volumes are not charge neutral, you shouldn't normally expect ions to be spread uniformly throughout them (unless the volume is very small). You should expect the ions to be squeezed into a thin layer along the walls of the chamber. This layer is called a "Debye layer" in electrochemistry or (usually) an "accumulation layer" in semiconductor device physics.